# Why is this simple code crashing a browser tab on all major browsers?

Tags: html, dom, crash, browser, metadata

I have a goal of showing one of 100 or so URLs on the screen for a few seconds, to be running within the same browser tab for weeks at a time.

I have a very simple PHP/HTML code that is accomplishing that with a meta-refresh, and yet once I launch it within a tab, the tab will crash within 24 hours, sometimes as soon as within 4-8 hours. That happens on Chrome, Safari and Firefox, although Chrome seems to last the longest.

Why?

https://gist.github.com/evaldasalex/5a7ee5722daeaf001b79

Comment: so when you say it crashes, what exactly happens? Is there an error message? The tab becomes unresponsive?

Answer (score 0):

A purely client-side JavaScript or AJAX solution might work better for you instead of using the meta refresh method.

If the URLs are just a hardcoded list then your solution can be done completely on the JavaScript side; no PHP required (except to serve the original HTML, CSS and JS).

Here is a solution that goes through a list of URLs and updates the iframe after a set interval: http://jsbin.com/lezuquma/1/edit?html,js,output

HTML:

```
<iframe id="fr" src="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page"
        style="border: 0; width:100%; height:100%;" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms"></iframe>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

JavaScript (Note: jQuery is used):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var urls = [
    "http://ImportOutpost.com",
    "http://blog.appannie.com/",
    "http://health.ucsd.edu/specialties/mindfulness/schedule/Pages/default.aspx",
    "http://www.treysmithblog.com/",
    "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)",
    "http://www.cafepress.com/cp/info/sell/index.aspx?area=openashop&page=openashop",
    "http://www.fiverr.com/categories/writing-translation/",
    "http://mashable.com/mobile/"
  ];

  var frame = $('#fr');

  setInterval(function() {
    var currentUrl = urls.shift();
    urls.push(currentUrl);

    frame.attr('src', currentUrl); 
  }, 10000);
});
```

If the URLs can't be hardcoded for whatever reason then just use AJAX to retrieve the URLs from the server to the client and employ the same method that I used above to refresh the iframe.

I only let me solution run for a few minutes so it might still breakdown if you let it run on for hours on end. Depending on the refresh interval you choose, this will be an intensive operation.

Comment: Thanks Sid but I have already tried something very similar using jQuery - it was crashing even faster than with meta-refresh.

Comment: @user1143919 Can I ask why are you trying to do this? Maybe there is a better way to achieve your goal.